# Async Send and Listen with amqp.node

Tags: amqp

I am trying to understand why when using amqp.node (https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node), it seems like I queue all my messages before I ever dequeue or handle these messages. I would expect the sending and receiving to be interleaved.

send-receive-send-receive

But I get

send-send-receive-receive

While inspecting my processes I see that I will first go through all of the sends before i get to any of the receives. I have written a simple demonstration of the problem I'm having

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');
var prettyHrtime = require('pretty-hrtime');
var when = require('when');

var firstMesssage = false;
var time, diff, totaltime;
var received = 0;

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', { noDelay: false } ).then(function(conn) {
  process.once('SIGINT', function() { conn.close(); });
  return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {

    var ok = ch.assertQueue('hello', {durable: false});

    ok = ok.then(function(_qok) {
      return ch.consume('hello', function(msg) {

        if(!firstMesssage){
          time = process.hrtime();
          firstMesssage = true;
        }

        received++;
        console.log(new Date().getTime());
        console.log(" [x] Received '%s' %s", msg.content.toString(), received);
        if(received >= 10000){
          diff = process.hrtime(time);
          var words = prettyHrtime(diff);
          console.log(words);
        }
      }, {noAck: true});
    });

    return ok.then(function(_consumeOk) {
      console.log(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C');
    });
  });
}).then(null, console.warn);



var numberToSend = 10000;
var numberDone = 0;

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', { noDelay: false } ).then(function(conn) {
  return when(conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
    var q = 'hello';
    var msg = 'Hello World!';

    var ok = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});

    function sendMsg(){
      ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
      console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg, new Date().getTime());
      numberDone++;
    }

    return ok.then(function(_qok) {
      while(numberDone < numberToSend){
        sendMsg();
      }
      console.log('*** done');
      return ch.close();

    });
  })).ensure(function() { conn.close(); });
}).then(null, console.warn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Node is single threaded so it *can't* process any of the incoming messages until your `while` loop that does all the sending has finished.

Try wrapping your `sendMsg` in a `setImmediate` call and see how that changes things *(it'll have to be converted to a promise and chained so that the channel and connect don't close before everything sends)*:

```
function sendMsg(resolve){
  setImmediate(function() {
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
    console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg, new Date().getTime());
    resolve();
  });
}

return ok.then(function(_qok) {
  var sendOk = when.promise(sendMsg);
  while(numberDone < numberToSend){
    sendOk = sendOk.then(function() {
      return when.promise(sendMsg);
    });
    numberDone++;
  }

  return sendOk.finally(function() {
    console.log('*** done');
    ch.close(); 
  });
});
```

You can see the difference in even just 5 messages:

```
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!' 1428467734962
 [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!' 1428467734963
1428467734965
 [x] Received 'Hello World!' 1
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!' 1428467734965
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!' 1428467734965
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!' 1428467734966
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!' 1428467734966
*** done
1428467735004
 [x] Received 'Hello World!' 2
1428467735005
 [x] Received 'Hello World!' 3
1428467735005
 [x] Received 'Hello World!' 4
1428467735005
 [x] Received 'Hello World!' 5
```

Comment: The answer is completely correct, but the example in the question is a bit contrived. The typical setup with node and rabbitmq is having separate processes as producers and consumers so the "thread blocking" problem with interleaved publishes and subscribes is not experienced often in the wild.